# At what cases should I include functions for managing a generic type in a struct?

Tags: c, struct

I am quite confused over this. Let me give you an example where my initial guess was wrong.

I have a generic datatype named `Amazon`, it stores listings of different products that users (identified only by their ID) would like to sell. Each listing contains the ID of the product (unique), the product itself (of generic type and identical for all products in a certain `Amazon`) and a minimal price.

If a user wants to purchase some product, he adds a bid to an existing list of previous bids. It is important to store previous bids even if the user was outbid.

In case it's not clear, the user supplies a free function and a copy function for the type of the product when the system is created.

My idea for implementing the system was to include three structs:

```
typedef void* product_type;
typedef product_type(*product_type_copy)(product_type);
typedef void(*product_type_free)(product_type);

struct amazon_t{
    Set listings;
    product_type_copy copy;
    product_type_free free;
};

struct product_info_t{
    List bids;
    int id;
    int min_price;
    product_type product;
};

struct bid_t{
    int bidder_id;
    int bid_sum;
};
```

Now, when I got my exam back I saw that points were deducted because the struct `product_info_t` was also supposed to contain the copy function and the free function of the type of the product, like this:

```
struct product_info_t{
    List bids;
    int id;
    int min_price;
    product_type product;
    product_type_copy copy;
    product_type_free free;
};
```

I can't understand why this is necessary. Can someone please explain why in this case I am supposed to add the functions to both structs?

Note: `Amazon` is the name of a pointer to `amazon_t`

Comment: @chux Amazon is the name of a pointer to amazon_t

Comment: OK.    Posting a description of code "Note: Amazon is the name of a pointer to amazon_t" is not as clear as posting code `typedef .... Amazon;`.

Comment: Because products differ from each other and need a different copy function. If all products were the same, you would need one copy function.

Comment: @KamilCuk it is stated that all the products are from the same type.

Comment: Why does every `product_info_t` have a copy of `copy` and `free`; shouldn't we use one virtual table for each object?

Comment: @NeilEdelman This is what I'm asking. My professor insists this is the way it is supposed to be done. I am yet to understand why.

Comment: If the user supplies the virtual functions every time a new product is created, then they should be with the product, but what does that mean exactly? a new product type, or an individual product? I think it's unclear whether that's `amazon_t` or `product_info_t`; is `amazon_t` the product type or the whole database? What is up with the member `void *product`? If `amazon_t` and `product_info_t` have the same virtual functions, I would ask what is meant by that.